# Line Graph D3.js Error : <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,289.8LNaN,27…"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

LineGraph is not plotted only the axis are shown.
Error shown is : d3.v4.min.js:2 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,289.8LNaN,27…".
The time is in Unix code maybe that's causing the error.
The file shows X-axis with time and Y-axis with temperature.
I have tried converting unix to a timestamp, but I need it in minutes/seconds.

The javascript Part :

```
 const xValue = d => new Date(d.timestamp * 1000);
    const xLabel = 'Time';
    const yValue = d => d.temprature;
    const yLabel = 'Temperature';
    const margin = { left: 120, right: 30, top: 20, bottom: 120 };

    const svg = d3.select('svg');
    const width = svg.attr('width');
    const height = svg.attr('height');
    const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
    const xAxisG = g.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`);
    const yAxisG = g.append('g');

    xAxisG.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'axis-label')
        .attr('x', innerWidth / 2)
        .attr('y', 100)
        .text(xLabel);

    yAxisG.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'axis-label')
        .attr('x', -innerHeight / 2)
        .attr('y', -60)
        .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text(yLabel);

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime();
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear();

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xScale)
        .tickPadding(15)
        .ticks(5)
        .tickSize(-innerHeight);

    const yTicks = 5;
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScale)
        .ticks(yTicks)
        .tickPadding(15)
        .tickSize(-innerWidth);

    const line = d3.line()
        .x(d => xScale(xValue(d)))
        .y(d => yScale(yValue(d)))
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);

    const row = d => {
        d.timestamp = new Date(d.timestamp * 1000);
        d.temprature = +d.temprature;
        return d;
    };

    d3.csv('http://localhost:8000/result.csv', row, data => {
        xScale
            .domain(d3.extent(data, xValue))
            .range([0, innerWidth]);

        yScale
            .domain(d3.extent(data, yValue))
            .range([innerHeight, 0])
            .nice(yTicks);

        g.append('path')
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
            .attr('stroke-width', 4)
            .attr('d', line(data));

        xAxisG.call(xAxis);
        yAxisG.call(yAxis);
    });
```

The CSV file :

```
temprature,time
22.34,1553974814384
24.77,1554453925188
25.09,1554455725250
25.73,1554457525395
```

Comment: In `const xValue = d => new Date(d.timestamp * 1000);` there is no `timestamp` in the data, it should be `time` instead. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you so much. Can you also help me converting it to mins:secs.